# ¿Como puedo obtener uno o más documentos de una colección de Firebase, utilizando 2 o más parámetros para filtrar la consulta?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

Soy totalmente nuevo en estos temas de ionic y firebase, sin embargo recientemente estoy tratando de realizar algunos ejercicios. Me he topado con un pequeño inconveniente, si bien es cierto navegando por internet encontre la forma de obtener documentos.

Comparto mi método para realizarlo.

```
 getCheckIn(email, day, month, year) {
return this.db.collection('attendance', 
ref => ref.where("email", "==", email)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(checks => {
  return checks.map( check => {
    const data = check.payload.doc.data() as Registry;
    data.idReg = check.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
  })
}));
```

}

Como se puede observar el método recibe 4 parámetros, actualmente solo filtra por "email" y me obtiene solo los documentos que poseen el valor de "email", quisiera que alguien me apoyara para poder incluir los 3 parámetros faltantes a modo de obtener los documentos que cumplan con los 4 valores de los parámetros recibidos en el método.

Por intuición podría agregar lo siguiente:

```
     getCheckIn(email, day, month, year) {
return this.db.collection('attendance', 
ref => ref.where("email", "==", email) /*&&  ref.where("day", "==", day)  && ref.where("month", "==", month) && ref.where("year", "==", year) */).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(checks => {
  return checks.map( check => {
    const data = check.payload.doc.data() as Registry;
    data.idReg = check.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
  })
}));
```

}

Sin embargo esto me devuelve documentos que no cumplen con los valores de los parámetros.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer consultas compuestas puedes enlazar las *queries* encadenando los métodos `where`. De ese modo se aplicaría una **`AND`** lógica.

```
getCheckIn(email, day, month, year) {
    // Condition chain
    const filter = ref => 
        ref.where("email", "==", email)
           .where('day', '==', day)
           .where('month', '==', month)
           .where('year', '==', year);

    return this.db.collection('attendance', filter)
                  .snapshotChanges()
                  .pipe(
                    map(checks =>
                        checks.map( check => {
                            const data = check.payload.doc.data() as Registry;
                            data.idReg = check.payload.doc.id;
                            return data;
                        })
                  ));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Hace un tiempo implementé una función que agilizaba el *chaining* de condiciones de igualdad.

```
const equals = (ref, values) =>
    Object.keys(values).reduce(
        (acc, curr) =>  acc.where(curr, '==', values[curr]),
        ref);
```

Básicamente admite la referencia por argumento y un objeto con todas las claves que van a servir de condición. El objeto de las claves, `values`, tendrá por *key* la clave en la base de datos y por *value* el valor a comparar.

Así quedaría el método `getCheckIn` haciendo uso de la función `equals`.

```
getCheckIn(email, day, month, year) {
    const conditions = { email, day, month, year };
    return this.db.collection('attendance', ref => equals(ref, conditions))
                  .snapshotChanges()
                  .pipe(
                    map(checks =>
                        checks.map( check => {
                            const data = check.payload.doc.data() as Registry;
                            data.idReg = check.payload.doc.id;
                            return data;
                        })
                  ));
}
```

La verdad que hice ya hace un tiempo esta función `equals` y no tengo del todo claro que funcione en tu caso. De todos modos me gustaría que me lo hicieras saber.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió mucho, funciona perfecto con las dos formas.